# Fail with preg_replace and regular expression

Tags: php, preg-replace, expression

I want to delete all the short word set, which start and end with `== ==`, like `== some text ==`.
I want to make that work with preg_replace, but it did not work.
This is my code:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[==][ ][a-z|A-Z|0-9][ ][==]/', "", $string);
```

Comment: You are putting a lot of things in brackets that shouldn’t be in brackets. Are you confusing them with parentheses? `/(==)( )(a-z|A-Z|0-9)( )(==)/` would work, though `/== [a-zA-Z0-9] ==/` will accomplish the same thing. Then you probably want to repeat characters, so `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`. Any text would be `.*?`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$string = preg_replace('/==.*?==/', '', $string);
```

*Yes, I know that the original pattern has additional checks, but I really doubt those will be useful. For completeness sake, though, here's the (most probably) original intent, written in proper regexian:*

```
$string = preg_replace('/== [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ==/', '', $string);
```

In your current regex you severely misuse the character classes (defined with brackets). First, character classes are useful for alternating between *single* characters only, so `[==]` is actually the same as `[=]` (and is less efficient in raw than just `=`).

Second, using alternation within the class itself is just meaningless: `[a-z|A-Z|0-9]` actually matches both letters, digits AND `|` sign. Proper way of using this class is `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.